# Finding limits through definitions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to prove the following statement and I am not really sure how to do it. I am not allowed to use any limit rules only definitions.

Evaluate the limit as $n$ goes to infinity for the following sequence $n^2/n!$.

Comment: Think about the behavior of $\frac{n^2}{n!}$ for big $n$ and come up with a guess as to what it might. Then use your guess in the proof using the definition.

Comment: A first step would be to notice that $\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $n>2$
$$0<\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\cdot \frac{n^2}{(n-1)n}< \frac{2}{n-2}.$$
What is the limit? Given $\epsilon>0$, is there $N>0$ such that for $n\geq N$ the right-hand side is less than $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n >4$; then :

$n-1 \gt n-2 \gt n/2.$

$ \dfrac{n^2}{n!} = \dfrac{n}{(n-1)!} \lt \dfrac{n}{(n-1)(n-2)} $

$\lt \dfrac{n}{(n/2)(n/2)} = 4/n.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

There is a $N_0$, integer, positive, with

$N_0 >4/\epsilon.$
(Archimedes)

For $n\ge N_0$ :

$\dfrac{n^2}{n!} \lt 4/n \lt 4/N_0 \lt \epsilon.$